# TimePicker In android showing error

Tags: android

```
DialogFragment timeFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
timeFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

I have try my time picker in my fragment like this. But in timeFragment.show() 
have error displaying "cannot resolve method 'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManger.java.lang.string)'. 
Here my TimePickerFragment();

```
 import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.format.DateFormat;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.app.DialogFragment;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import java.util.Calendar;
 import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements      TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

//onTimeSet() callback method
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){

    Log.d("Choosen Time = ","Hour : " + String.valueOf(hourOfDay)
            + "\nMinute : " + String.valueOf(minute) + "\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

 FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(;
        DatePickerFragment dialog = new DatePickerFragment();
        dialog.show(fm, "timeFragment");
```

DatePickerFragment() must extend from: android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment

Comment: I Got it . I have wrong extend from android.app.DialogFragment Thx

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you imported

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
```

for the Dialog Fragment instead of

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

I'm using androidx